# jQuery - Improving code and eliminating repetition

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, maintainability

I have a series of calls to various jQuery methods and I was just wondering if there was a way to clean this code up, turn it into a function that I pass the selectors into, or anything else that could make the the code more manageable/maintainable. What I have is a very long list of lines of code like these with a lot of repetition:

```
...
$('#boxcolor').on('change', function() {
    $('header').css('background-color', $('#boxcolor').val());
});
$('#color').on('change', function(){
    $('header').css('color',$('#color').val());
});
$('#size').keyup(function() {
    $('header').css('font-size', $('#size').val() + 'px');    
});
...
```

Any suggestions would be great, thanks.

Comment: I don't see much actual repetition in this particular snipet. Are you doing the same exact set of things to more elements than "header"? Generally I see a tradeoff between lots of refactoring to make code small and readability -- some spacing things out can help you later when maintaining the code.

Answer (score 5):

Just my suggestion:

```
var header = $('header');

$('#boxcolor').change({
    property: 'background-color'
}, handler );

$('#color').change({
    property: 'color'
}, handler );

$('#size').keyup({
    property: 'font-size',
    unit: 'px'
}, handler );

function handler( e ) {
    header.css( e.data.property, $( this ).val() + ( e.data.unit || "" ) );
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but in my opinion is less readable than the original one. Still +1

Comment: Just some formatting in those objects, and ta-da!

Comment: Nice way of using data transfer :) Unfortunately this will lock you into only being able to make css changes, unless you wrap *that* as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a lot of things you could refactor, but, if you are always selecting the header, you could do:

```
var changeHeaderStyles = function() {
   var header = $('header');
   //use a clousure here to only get the header once
   return function(cssObject) {
       $header.css(cssObject);
   }
}(); 

//Then..
$('#size').keyup(function() {
    changeHeaderStyles({ 'font-size': $('#size').val() + 'px' });    
});
```

So then you could change more than one style at once, and you can read clearly what is happening.

Hope it helps